# (:category_name/:id) Kind of routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, friendly-url

I have these models:

```
Category(:name)
Post(:category_id, :title, :body)
```

The category model only has a handful amount of categories, Currently my possible routes are:

```
/tasks/15015
/categories/5/posts/5641841
```

I'd like to have a friendly url in this format, but i can't figure out a way to not go completely wildcard and mess up the other routes:

```
/politics/518-obama-health-care
```

As i said, i tried this but i'm looking for something less wildcard and more integrated with the current categories if possible:

```
match '(:category_name)/(:id)' => 'posts#show'
```

Any other ideas are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Just put it last, so it doesn't mess with any of your other routes.  Then put a `before_filter` (only for `show`) in your `PostsController` that checks to make sure that `:category_name` is valid and if it's not raise an `ActionController::RoutingError`